# Match Value and Get its Column Header in python

Tags: python, pandas

[Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2czjh.png)

I have 1000 by 6 dataframe, where A,B,C,D were rated by people on scale of 1-10.

In SELECT column, I have a value, which in all cases is same as value in either of A/B/C/D.

I want to change value in 'SELECT' to name of column to which it matches. For example, for ID 1, SELECT = 1, and D = 1, so the value of select should change to D.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel("u.xlsx",sheet_name = "Sheet2",header = 0)
```

But I am lost how to proceed.

Comment: Please add the sample in your question and not with a link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gwenersl solution compare all columns without `ID` and `SELECT` filtered by [`difference`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.difference.html) with [`DataFrame.eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.eq.html) (`==`), check first `True` value by [`idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.idxmax.html) and also if not exist matching value is set value `no match` with [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
cols = df.columns.difference(['ID','SELECT'])
mask = df[cols].eq(df['SELECT'], axis=0)

df['SELECT'] = np.where(mask.any(axis=1), mask.idxmax(axis=1), 'no match')
print (df)
   ID  A  B  C  D SELECT
0   1  4  9  7  1      D
1   2  5  7  2  8      C
2   3  7  4  8  6      C
```

**Detail**:

```
print (mask)
       A      B      C      D
0  False  False  False   True
1  False  False   True  False
2  False  False   True  False
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the values in A, B, C, D are unique in each row with respect to SELECT, I'd do it like this:

```
>>> df
   ID  A  B  C  D  SELECT
0   1  4  9  7  1       1
1   2  5  7  2  8       2
2   3  7  4  8  6       8
>>>
>>> df_abcd = df.loc[:, 'A':'D']
>>> df['SELECT'] = df_abcd.apply(lambda row: row.isin(df['SELECT']).idxmax(), axis=1)
>>> df
   ID  A  B  C  D SELECT
0   1  4  9  7  1      D
1   2  5  7  2  8      C
2   3  7  4  8  6      C
```

Answer (score 1):

Use -

```
df['SELECT2'] = df.columns[pd.DataFrame([df['SELECT'] == df['A'], df['SELECT'] == df['B'], df['SELECT'] == df['C'], df['SELECT'] == df['D']]).transpose().idxmax(1)+1]
```

**Output**

```
    ID  A   B   C   D   SELECT  SELECT2
0   1   4   9   7   1   1   D
1   2   5   7   2   8   2   C
2   3   7   4   8   6   8   C
```